# PySpark data skewness with Window Functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a huge PySpark dataframe and I'm doing a series of Window functions over partitions defined by my key.

The issue with the key is, my partitions gets skewed by this and results in Event Timeline that looks something like this,

[image]

I know that I can use salting technique to solve this issue when I'm doing a join. But how can I solve this issue when I'm using Window functions?

I'm using functions like lag, lead etc in the Window functions. I can't do the process with salted key, because I'll get wrong results.

How to solve skewness in this case?

I'm looking for a dynamic way of repartitioning my dataframe without skewness.

Updates based on answer from @jxc

I tried creating a sample df and tried running code over that,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=150000)
df['id'] = df['id'].map(lambda x: 100 if x % 2 == 0 else x)
df['timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'), periods=len(df), freq='60s')
sdf = sc.createDataFrame(df)
sdf = sdf.withColumn("amt", F.rand()*100)
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")

sdf = sdf.withColumn("new_col", F.lag("amt").over(w) + F.lead("amt").over(w))
x = sdf.toPandas()
```

This gave me a event timeline like this,

[image]

I tried the code from @jxc's answer,

```
sdf = sc.createDataFrame(df)
sdf = sdf.withColumn("amt", F.rand()*100)

N = 24*3600*365*2
sdf_1 = sdf.withColumn('pid', F.ceil(F.unix_timestamp('timestamp')/N))

w1 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid').orderBy('timestamp')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid')

sdf_2 = sdf_1.select(
    '*',
    F.count('*').over(w2).alias('cnt'),
    F.row_number().over(w1).alias('rn'),
    (F.lag('amt',1).over(w1) + F.lead('amt',1).over(w1)).alias('new_val')
)

sdf_3 = sdf_2.filter('rn in (1, 2, cnt-1, cnt)') \
    .withColumn('new_val', F.lag('amt',1).over(w) + F.lead('amt',1).over(w)) \
    .filter('rn in (1,cnt)')
    
df_new = sdf_2.filter('rn not in (1,cnt)').union(sdf_3)

x = df_new.toPandas()
```

I ended up one additional stage and the event timeline looked more skewed,

[image]

Also the run time is increased by a bit with new code

Comment: If the skewed key is known upfront, you can split your dataframe on it, compute window functions for skewed key separately, and then `union` the results.

Comment: I'm afraid, Skewness is not known in advance. It can change time to time. For example, for a particular dataset, they keys will not bring any skewness. But for some other data (same columns but more rows); they keys may result in skewness

Comment: As long as you know what key **values** are prone to skewing, you can still split dataframe and process sets independently, no?

Comment: I know which keys will bring skewness, but don't know whether it is will be there for a given dataset. I agree, still I can split and union the data. But I can't figure how to split in such a way that partitions are not skewed in the splitted data frames.

Comment: You're right, now I too think it might not be effective with window lag/lead functions, since they will still require a singlepartition exchange. Sorry...

Comment: can you give more info like which version of spark you are using and the DAG visualization and  stage metrics for this task, this will really help in understanding more about what is going on.

Comment: I'm using spark 2.3 and pyspark. Stage metrics are skewed when window functions are used. Median is around 10 ms and max is at 2 mints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To process a large partition, you can try split it based on the *orderBy* column(most likely a numeric column or date/timestamp column which can be converted into numeric) so that all new sub-partitions maintain the correct order of rows. process rows with the new partitioner and for calculation using `lag` and `lead` functions, only rows around the boundary between sub-partitions need to be post-processed. (Below also discussed how to merge small partitions in task-2)

Use your example `sdf` and assume we have the following WinSpec and a simple aggregate function:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('timestamp')
df.withColumn('new_amt', F.lag('amt',1).over(w) + F.lead('amt',1).over(w))
```

### Task-1: split large partitions:

Try the following:

1. select a **N** to split *timestamp* and set up an additional partitionBy column **pid** (using `ceil`, `int`, `floor` etc.):

   ```
   # N to cover 35-days' intervals
   N = 24*3600*35
   df1 = sdf.withColumn('pid', F.ceil(F.unix_timestamp('timestamp')/N))
   ```
2. add *pid* into partitionBy(see **w1**), then calaulte `row_number()`, `lag()` and `lead()` over **w1**. find also number of rows (**cnt**) in each new partition to help identify the end of partitions (`rn == cnt`). the resulting **new_val** will be fine for majority of rows except those on the boundaries of each partition.

   ```
   w1 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid').orderBy('timestamp')
   w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid')

   df2 = df1.select(
       '*',
       F.count('*').over(w2).alias('cnt'),
       F.row_number().over(w1).alias('rn'),
       (F.lag('amt',1).over(w1) + F.lead('amt',1).over(w1)).alias('new_amt')
   )
   ```

   Below is an example `df2` showing the boundary rows.

   [image]
3. process the boundary: select rows which are on the boundaries `rn in (1, cnt)` plus those which have values used in the calculation `rn in (2, cnt-1)`, do the same calculation of *new_val* over **w** and save result for boundary rows only.

   ```
   df3 = df2.filter('rn in (1, 2, cnt-1, cnt)') \
       .withColumn('new_amt', F.lag('amt',1).over(w) + F.lead('amt',1).over(w)) \
       .filter('rn in (1,cnt)')
   ```

   Below shows the resulting *df3* from the above *df2*

   [image]
4. merge *df3* back to *df2* to update boundary rows `rn in (1,cnt)`

   ```
   df_new = df2.filter('rn not in (1,cnt)').union(df3)
   ```

   Below screenshot shows the final *df_new* around the boundary rows:

   [image]

   ```
   # drop columns which are used to implement logic only
   df_new = df_new.drop('cnt', 'rn')
   ```

**Some Notes:**

1. the following 3 WindowSpec are defined:

   ```
   w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('timestamp')          <-- fix boundary rows
   w1 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid').orderBy('timestamp')  <-- calculate internal rows
   w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'pid')                       <-- find #rows in a partition
   ```

   **note**: strictly, we'd better use the following `w` to fix boundary rows to avoid issues with tied `timestamp` around the boundaries.

   ```
   w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('pid', 'rn')          <-- fix boundary rows
   ```
2. if you know which partitions are skewed, just divide them and skip others. the existing method might split a small partition into 2 or even more if they are sparsely distributed

   ```
   df1 = df.withColumn('pid', F.when(F.col('id').isin('a','b'), F.ceil(F.unix_timestamp('timestamp')/N)).otherwise(1))
   ```

   If for each partition, you can retrieve `count`(number of rows) and `min_ts`=min(timestamp), then try something more dynamically for `pid`(below `M` is the threshold number of rows to split):

   ```
   F.expr(f"IF(count>{M}, ceil((unix_timestamp(timestamp)-unix_timestamp(min_ts))/{N}), 1)")
   ```

   **note:** for skewness inside a partition, will requires more complex functions to generate `pid`.
3. if only `lag(1)` function is used, just post-process left boundaries, filter by `rn in (1, cnt)` and update only `rn == 1`

   ```
   df3 = df1.filter('rn in (1, cnt)') \
       .withColumn('new_amt', F.lag('amt',1).over(w)) \
       .filter('rn = 1')
   ```

   similar to lead function when we need only to fix right boundaries and update `rn == cnt`
4. if only `lag(2)` is used, then filter and update more rows with `df3`:

   ```
   df3 = df1.filter('rn in (1, 2, cnt-1, cnt)') \
       .withColumn('new_amt', F.lag('amt',2).over(w)) \
       .filter('rn in (1,2)')
   ```

   You can extend the same method to mixed cases with both `lag` and `lead` having different offset.

### Task-2: merge small partitions:

Based on the number of records in a partition `count`, we can set up an threshold `M` so that if `count>M`, the *id* holds its own partition, otherwise we merge partitions so that #of total records is less than `M` (below method has a edging case of `2*M-2`).

```
M = 20000

# create pandas df with columns `id`, `count` and `f`, sort rows so that rows with count>=M are located on top
d2 = pd.DataFrame([ e.asDict() for e in sdf.groupby('id').count().collect() ]) \
    .assign(f=lambda x: x['count'].lt(M)) \
    .sort_values('f')    

# add pid column to merge smaller partitions but the total row-count in partition should be less than or around M 
# potentially there could be at most `2*M-2` records for the same pid, to make sure strictly count<M, use a for-loop to iterate d1 and set pid:
d2['pid'] = (d2.mask(d2['count'].gt(M),M)['count'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()/M).astype(int)

# add pid to sdf. In case join is too heavy, try using Map
sdf_1 = sdf.join(spark.createDataFrame(d2).alias('d2'), ["id"]) \
    .select(sdf["*"], F.col("d2.pid"))

# check pid: # of records and # of distinct ids
sdf_1.groupby('pid').agg(F.count('*').alias('count'), F.countDistinct('id').alias('cnt_ids')).orderBy('pid').show()
+---+-----+-------+                                                             
|pid|count|cnt_ids|
+---+-----+-------+
|  0|74837|      1|
|  1|20036|    133|
|  2|20052|    134|
|  3|20010|    133|
|  4|15065|    100|
+---+-----+-------+
```

Now, the new Window should be partitioned by **pid** alone and move *id* to `orderBy`, see below:

```
w3 = Window.partitionBy('pid').orderBy('id','timestamp')
```

customize lag/lead functions based on the above **w3** WinSpec, and then  calculate **new_val**:

```
lag_w3  = lambda col,n=1: F.when(F.lag('id',n).over(w3) == F.col('id'), F.lag(col,n).over(w3))
lead_w3 = lambda col,n=1: F.when(F.lead('id',n).over(w3) == F.col('id'), F.lead(col,n).over(w3))

sdf_new = sdf_1.withColumn('new_val', lag_w3('amt',1) + lead_w3('amt',1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will make sure that I fully understand it by reading throughly and running experiments from my side.

Comment: I was wondering whether similar operations can be done over any other operation. For example, max, min, when (sql function) being  applied over windowspec?

Comment: max, min does not apply with this method, you might have to preprocess them separately (split the partition, count and then sum-count) and then join the values back.

Comment: @SreeramTP, do you mind to add a feedback to my answer or let me know with any problems? thanks.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand how it works. If my partitions are already skewed with just the keys I have right now (p_col), then adding a new key to there should increase the skewness as smaller partitions will be split in to smaller ones

Comment: @SreeramTP, the method I suggested is to handle very huge partitions which can not be loaded into any executor memory and thus lead to OOM issue. if your data are all small except 3-4 relatively bigger partitions. This will certainly be overkilled. AS I mentioned in Notes item-(2), we can add variable _pid_ only to those large partitions, for example, set up a threshold to number_of_rows_in_partition, and find min(timestamp) so that the sub-partition can be cut to reduce the potential small first sub-partition etc.

Comment: Also, this answer is providing more of a method instead a solution for all potential cases. you might have to make some manual adjustment to fit your actual data. any automated setup will have some costs. for example, if you want to automatically find `N` based on daterange and number of rows in side each partition etc. I was thinking of the skewness issue more about the huge data so to avoid join, groupby etc. but you might have a different concern. I will check this back around noon or evening at my time..

Comment: Makes sense. I'm worried about the smaller partitions. I'm not that concerned about bigger ones as I have sufficient resources to handle those bigger partitions. I liked your idea to split the bigger partitions only based on a N value. Will be great if you can add a small example.

Comment: @SreeramTP, added a section to merge small partitions, please drop me a line for any questions.

Answer (score 1):

To handle such skewed data, there are a couple of things you can try out.

1. If you are using *Databricks* to run your jobs and you know which column will have the skew then you can try out an option called [skew hint](https://kb.databricks.com/data/skew-hints-in-join.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20perform%20a%20join%20command%20with%20DataFrame,DataFrame%20for%20which%20you%20specify%20the%20skew%20hint.)
2. I recommend moving to *Spark 3.0* since you will have the option to use *[Adaptive Query Execution (AQE)](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/10/21/faster-sql-adaptive-query-execution-in-databricks.html)* which can handle most of the issues improving your job health and potentially running them faster.
3. Usually, I suggest making your data more even-sized partitions before any wide operation, and Increasing the cluster size does help but I am not sure if this will work for you.

Comment: I'm not using databricks. I'm using cloudera. I'm on older spark version so aqe is not an option for me. How to make my data in even sized partitions? Do you mean to repartition data based on it's size and distribute it evenly across partitions?

Comment: What's is your current cluster configuration and data load size & format?  You can write your data into a intermediate location in parquet format, preferably _repartition_ them such that your part files are around a little less than a GB each.

Comment: Cluster is huge. 128 executors, 32gb per executor. I'm loading data from hive which is already partitioned based on size. I tried different spark parallelism and found 1000 works for my data and spark configuration. So I load the data from hive, partitionBy on some columns and find lag, lead etc on some columns. For some datasets, where I don't have skew in the keys, I could get result in few seconds. But when there is skew I have to wait for couple of minutes. By result I meant writing back to hive after computing needed columns with window functions.